# What if two mages use the "beast friend" spell on the same creature?

Tags: savage-worlds

What happens if a second mage attempts to "Beast Friend" a creature that has already been "Beast Friend"-ed by another mage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd just treat it as a contested roll, higher spellcasting result wins.

You could also rule that until the first Beast Friend is dispelled, it can't be overridden.

Comment: I went for the first option, but wonders if there anything I had missed.

Comment: I had a quick look on the Great White Games/Pinnacle Entertainment Group forum and no one has asked that question. The nearest is http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=16009&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=beast+friend

Comment: Note: in a draw, the attacker wins.  So if the second mage rolls just as well as the first one, the second mage gets the beast.